# InternetExplorer - RemoteWebDriver, how to specify the path to the executable file?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-grid

I've been trying to get my Grid working with IE, but at some point I need to specify the full path to my driver's exe.

```
InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
DesiredCapabilities ieCapability = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
ieCapability.SetCapability(ieOptions.EnsureCleanSession.ToString(), true);
ieCapability.SetCapability(ieOptions.BrowserCommandLineArguments.ToString(), "-private");
```

I need to know if this can be done via `InternetExplorerOptions` or `DesiredCapabilities` or if I just should create an environment variable holding the path to my IE driver.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most common practices i've seen in my Selenium experience, is testers will put their statement in their super class.

Consider the following (I'm a Java programmer, so this will be java code, you can convert to C#):

```
  public class SuperTest {
    public SuperTest() {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Path\\To\\IEDriver.exe");
    }
  }
  public class Test extends SuperTest {}
```

You can see how you can do it in the [Getting started with Selenium framework](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium/blob/master/src/main/java/com/company/seleniumframework/AutomationTest.java#L133) (again, Java).

Comment: I might be going with this approach since it's what i found everywhere! Thanks for your response.